# Software minetest problem

Tags: software-center

All the software in the center are on their older virsions and the update software doesn't detect the programmer.
I want to play minetest 0.4.6 but the one in the software scenter is 0.3.1 
if i try to download the 0.4.6 from the internet , the software center doesn't aloww me to install it.
And i have the newest ubuntu (13.4)
Please update it

Answer (score 1):

Zander, new versions often come with bugs, so to avoid massive problems with packages, the stable versions, not the newest, appear in the softwarecenter. I think that's ok.

By the way, I have Minetest Version 0.4.4 in the repositories, not 0.3.1!

I looked on the project homepage, and there are .deb files to download for 0.4.7.

https://code.launchpad.net/~minetestdevs/+archive/stable/+packages

Uninstall outdated Minetest-package. Then install the program Gdebi from the Softwarecenter.

Download

for amd64: 
minetestc55_0.4.7-0ppa1~raring1_amd64.deb

or for 32-bit: 
minetestc55_0.4.7-0ppa1~raring1_i386.deb

Got to your Download-folder and right click on the downloaded Minetest-package - Open with... - Gdebi installer - Ok. The package should install. When it's done close Gdebi and search in the Dash for Minetest.